# Dart+Polymer as a webpage/app/extension not working outside of Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I wrote a Dart-Polymer app in Dart Editor (Win7Pro64). Everything works perfectly in Dartium and running as Javascript in Chrome, but I am unable to load a working version outside of the IDE.

When opening the html file (there's only one) in Chrome (36.0.1985.103 beta-m), the background image is there, but the rest of the UI is nonexistent or unstyled (paper elements seem to not be there). Dart/JavaScript also doesn't appear to be executing.

Loading it as an unpacked extension into Chrome (as an app or extension, see manifests below) results in almost exactly the same result. UI components were all there, but unstyled and without Dart/JavaScript functionality. However, the paper-ripple effect did work, so maybe it is just my scripts not running.

In case it matters, I tried not only the `build/web/` folder, but the `out/web/` and `web/` folders too.

**EDIT**: app.html will open in Chrome successfully (from Windows). But, when loading as a Chrome app or exension, I get a whole slew of errors: http://pastebin.com/KRXnaTXi. Since they all seem CSP related, here is the first:

```dart
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed 
source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 
'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 
'default-src' is used as a fallback.
 observe.js:988
(anonymous function) observe.js:988
(anonymous function) observe.js:992
(anonymous function) wrappers.js:374
```

**/EDIT**

Okay on to the code:

**pubspec.yaml**

When loading as an extension, I used `csp: true` and made sure the built html file used the `*.precompiled.js` script.

```dart
name: app
description: desc
dependencies:
    polymer: ">=0.12.0 <0.13.0"
    core_elements: ">=0.1.1 <0.2.0"
    paper_elements: ">=0.1.0+2 <0.2.0"
    crypto: ">=0.9.0"
    cipher: ">=0.7.0 <0.8.0"
    lawndart: ">=0.6.5 <0.7.0"
    chrome: ">=0.6.0 <0.7.0"    
transformers:
- chrome
- polymer:
    entry_points: 
    - web/app.html
    csp: false
```

Even though it's not needed to run the app from the editor (in a Dartium/Chrome tab), I have a manifest for loading it as an app.

**manifest.json**

```dart
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "app",
  "description": "desc",
  "version": "0.1.0",

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "128": "images/icon128.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "16": "images/icon16.png"
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';" 
}
```

If loading as an extension, the "app": section would be replaced by:

```dart
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "app.html"    
},
```

Another thing tested was the `--deploy` argument in `build.dart`.

```dart
import 'package:polymer/builder.dart';

main(args) {
  build(entryPoints: ['web/grujin.html'],
        options: parseOptions(args));
//        options: parseOptions(['--deploy']));
}
```

**app.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <script src='packages/web_components/platform.js'></script>
     not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
<script src='packages/web_components/dart_support.js'></script>
<link rel='import' href='packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html'>
<!-- Other imports ... -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='app.css' shim-shadowdom>
<script src='packages/browser/dart.js'></script>
</head>
<body fullbleed unresolved>
<paper-input id='passwd' label='password'></paper-input>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
    var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
    navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
      drawerPanel.togglePanel();
    });
  });
</script>
<script type='application/dart' src='app.dart'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_input.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_toast.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_checkbox.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_button.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_fab.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_slider.dart';
import 'package:lawndart/lawndart.dart';

export 'package:polymer/init.dart';

void main() {      
  initPolymer().run(() {
    // code here works most of the time
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {     
      // some things must wait until onReady callback is called
      // for an example look at the discussion linked below

      PaperInput passwd = querySelector('#passwd');              
      InputElement input = passwd.shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot.querySelector('input');
      input.type = 'password';
      // initialize polymer elements, etc...
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What does 'unable to load' or 'does not work' mean exactly. Any error messag?

Comment: I edited the question with a pastebin of error msgs (seem csp related). Here's the repo if you want to try it yourself https://github.com/jphilli85/grujin.git.

Comment: The first line of the errors has a CSP issue with loading polymer; the line: `<script src="packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js"></script>` is referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Gunter's answer a little further, this is how I was able to use vulcanize in Windows; allowing successful loading as an extension or app.

1. Download and install Node.js from http://nodejs.org/#download.
2. Open a command prompt, and type `npm install -g vulcanize` to install the vulcanize executable to `%AppData%\npm\node_modules\vulcanize\bin\`. (I believe the -g option can be omitted)
3. Run the executable on the HTML file in `.\build\web\` using the `--csp` option (see [here](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize#content-security-policy) for other command options).

   `vulcanize --csp -o build\web\app.html build\web\app.html`

Answer (score 2):

I tried it and it looks fine in Dartium (36.0.1985.97 (282401)), Chrome (Version 36.0.1985.125) and Firefox (30.0) but not in Dartium as extension. I wonder why it even loads as extension from `web` I thought extensions are supposed to be loaded from `app` only (see https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/tree/master/ide/app).

It seems paper-elements/core-elements have known issues in Chrome Apps

- https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/issues/42
- https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/613

Comment: There is no app/ directory in the project. I normally load the app/extension from the build/web/ directory using Chrome's extension interface. The issues you linked seem exactly my problem, I'm going to try this "vulcanize" thing.

Comment: There are still two inline scripts after vulcanization. One inside `<core-toolbar>` and one inside `<core-menu>`. Here is an image of the two elements: http://oi60.tinypic.com/v5v12a.jpg. I tried to do [alt registration](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#altregistration), but the script still shows up in Chrome dev tools. Should I download those elements offline and modify them or is there a better way?

Comment: An upated version of these elements should be published soon. Maybe this is fixed already. You could try to use the elements from the GitHub repo git@github.com:dart-lang/core-elements.git in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Use of NodeJS is not required - the same thing can be achieved by adding CSP options to the transformers in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
transformers:
  - polymer:
      csp: true
  - $dart2js:
      csp: true
```

Be sure to run `Pub Build` after any code changes, and use the files under `build/web` for your extension.